# Imapala server is not getting started

Tags: impala

I am currently using HADOOP 2.2.0 , HIVE 0.12.0 and Impala 1.2.3. When i am trying to start imapala -server its not getting started. When i checked the log directory , i am getting the following error.
Any help is highly appreciated.

```
Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Message missing required fields: callId, status; 
Host Details : local host is: "XXXX/[IP-ADDESS]"; destination host is: "hadoop-master":9000;
E0219 13:15:16.223870 22635 impala-server.cc:403] Aborting Impala Server startup due to improper configuration
```

Comment: You are missing some configuration...

Comment: Hi, Cloud you solve this problem ?I f so please let me know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop 2.2 is using protobuf 2.5 and Impala is using protobuf 2.4.0a .

Unfortunately code generated with protobuf 2.5 is incompatible with older protobuf libraries.

You can check JIRA ISSUE(HADOOP-9845) for the background or design decision to upgrade protobuf in Hadoop.

**SOLUTION**

1. Remove older protobuf .
2. Install protbuf 2.5
3. Build Impala

Comment: Hello Bliks,                                                             Thanks for the help. But can you please help me to build impala. As i am installing impala using yum install. So how can i build impala after changing the protbuf